# How to get Proguard to `keepclassmembers` of entire package

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

As title says: How do I get Proguard to `keepclassmembers` of entire package? Also to net delete methods with `void` signatures.

Answer (score 8):

To keep all class members (fields and methods) of all classes in a given package and all of its subpackages:

```
-keepclassmembers class mypackage.** { *; }
```

This includes void methods. To only keep all void methods:

```
-keepclassmembers class mypackage.** { void *(...); }
```

These are unusual settings though, because keeping all class members or all void methods (without even keeping all classes) seems like a very random requirement.

For most configurations, `-keep` is more appropriate than `-keepclassmembers`, relevant classes are typically only public ones (matching `public class`), relevant classes typically extend a specific class or interface (e.g. matching `extends somepackage.SomeClass`), and relevant class members are typically a very specific set of public methods (e.g. public setters, matching `public void set*(***)`).